# Почему литерал - константное значение? (вопрос новичка)

Tags: c#

[image: ccc]

Привет. Я недавно начал изучать программирование. Читаю книгу по C# и возник вопрос на главе литералы.
Я так понимаю что литерал это представление значения какого-то типа данных. Почему их называют "константные значения (которые нельзя изменить)"?

`int a = 40; //40 здесь это литерал`

Тут например я не понимаю как 40 это константное значение? Я же могу изменить и написать любое число на том месте? По этой логике все возможные в природе числа, строки и все остальное это тоже константы?)

Comment: нельзя написать `40 = 100`

Comment: В переменную можно записать любое значение, но если вы записали новое значение, само старое значение от этого не поменяется, например a = 100; "40" - не поменялось, поменялось "a".

Comment: "Я же могу изменить и написать любое число на том месте?" Всё можно изменить в compile time, константы не изменяются в runtime.